# Set colour in CSS for link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am trying to set the colour on my link to green however I am unable to work it out. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

The code:

```
        <div id="column-2" class="col2">
            <div class="off">
                <h2 class="SchoolProject" rel="column-2">
                    SCHOOL PROJECT
                </h2>
                <div class="image">
                    &#160;
                </div>
                <center>
                    <a id="test" href="ProjectOne.aspx">Project One</a>
                    <br />
```

I am trying to the the link "Project One" to green.  Can you please advise what I should add in the underlying CSS file?

> .page-wrapper div.services-us-wrapper div.col2 div.test {
>     color:Green; }

Thank you

P

Comment: Don't use div in front of the classnames. Also, is there any need to be so specific?

Comment: .page-wrapper div.services-us-wrapper div.col2 a { color:Green; } just use a instead of the id name of the link

Comment: @feat.martin the a element only has an ID not a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector says `div.test` but:

- There are no divs which are a member of the `test` class
- The anchor has an **id** `test`

You need to write a selector that actually matches the anchor.

Replacing `div.test` with `a` will do that.

Answer (score 1):

As your a-Element has an ID you can simply write
`#test { color: green; }`

Answer (score -2):

add `style="color:green"` in your `<a>` tag